# Streaming HLS/DASH video using expo-av - Change subtitiles/quality

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to stream HLS/DASH video using expo-av, and I want to have custom controls. I am not able to find examples to change the quality of the video and set subtitles. Any guidance on how to do it?